# On Linux, could any system event prevent the copy command from working?

Tags: linux, cp

Trying to determine if there is a scenario in which the copy command may fail.

I don't mean something like $PATH not set or file missing, but more in line with if the file is being edited, if the file is a binary file and being accessed by a system process or if its a database file which is being accessed.

Some basic testing seems to indicate the cp command works fine even if the file is being edited but not sure if there are any OS commands or scenarios in which a cp would fail. For example, what if its a database file and being updated/saved as the exact time the cp takes place. Something like this would be hard to test yet may occur.

Would there be a list of scenarios in which the system prevents a cp command from executing?

Comment: When you don't have permission for accessing the file, (rwx) permission lack won't allow you copy the file!

Comment: What I can think of: mandatory file lock on the source, not enough space on the destination, insuficient permissions, disk read error. Editing is OK. You should even be able to `rm` the file while the `cp` operation is in progress (effectively turning the operation into a badly performing `mv`).

Comment: Insufficient permissions, not enough space and disk read errors are the scenarios I was excluding. 

The items mandatory file locks sound more of what I was looking for but a quick search shows it affects a number of commands but copy was not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways `cp` might not do what you want.

Particular example that comes to mind:   If you have a process that can read the destination of `cp` at any given time, there is **no possible way** to guarantee the reader won't start reading before `cp` is done copying and end up reading a partially written file.  On small-ish files, this race condition may always work out in your favor, but it's still there.

The only way you can have a file that is always updated "atomically" from the perspective of readers such they always get either the old version or the new version, never a partial new version is via the `rename` system call.  Which *should* be what `mv` uses for files on the same volume/partition.

Implementing `cp` is, at the very least 5 system calls: 2x `open`, 1x `sendfile`, 2x `close`.

So just be aware that even if `cp` succeeds, there can still be race conditions and unpredictable behavior.

Comment: As far as generating an incomplete copy then was somewhat expected and understood as a possibility. I am mostly concerned with the copy command actually failing because of some other activity being done to the file. I searched but unable to find such a scenario but that does not mean one does not exist. As a result, I posted the question hoping someone who is much more intimate with the OS operations and possible conflicts could confirm or give some scenario.

Comment: Trouble with asking if the user space command line utility `cp` can fail, but from the perspective of a kernel developer is that there is no one, single answer.   On a given Linux distro, there could be 5 different implementations since there's `/bin/cp` and its probably a built-in for most shells.  Who knows if `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc, etc use the impl.

Comment: Good point and that now only adds to the complexity of the question.